# Retrieve only one rows with two status

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

Below is my data.

[image: Data]

I want to see the Job status only. I'm taking Job Name ans Status in Matrix and it is showing mw the job status as well if job is successfully completed. but the problem is if a job is failed the it is showing me two status for one job. Success and Failed both. where in I only want to see if all step is success then it should show success and it any of step is failed then it should show as failed with one row or if it is running then it should show as running.

Below is the output which I'm getting right now.

[image]

Where in the expected output is as below.

[image]

This is because one step is completed and one step is failed and it is showing both result since it is not unique. hence requesting you to kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: So, how do you generate this report currently? You probably want to display only the lastest status of a job, which shouldn't be too hard if you have a step number ...

Comment: Hi @derpirscher

could you please suggest me how to show only max step id result in table visual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only last step then create a measure and put it to the matrix (or filter pane);

```
MeasuretoCheckLastStep = 
var _lastStep = calculate( max(Table[StepID]), FILTER(ALL(Table), Table[JobName] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[JobName]) )

return if(_lastStep = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[StepID]) , 1, 0)
```